# Ratetod text fexir

Tags: code-golf

I heva this wierd text where vewols seem to be ratetod :

> I'm a badly written text. Some lunatic guy played with the order of vowels. Please fix me !

So I'd need a pragrom which can rateto the vewols (and the 'y' letter as it seems) back so that the text is raadeble agian.

Ouy can choeso the lungaega of ouyr chieco privedod ouy meka a cempleto pragrom (so not just a finctoun). The yntre can be an unpit feild, a text feli, or the cammond leni. The uutpot mya olsa vyra as ouy leki.

Of cuerso I'll anvilid yna pragrom uutpitong bad texts. There's no vulea in a pragrom which mekas texts ouy can't endarstund. But ouy can wreti ouyr cemmonts and qeistouns in ratetod texts if ouy want.

---

#### Clarifications

- Your program is only required to handle ASCII text.
- For the purposes of this question, the following characters are vowels: `aeiouy`
- The positions of the vowels within each word should be rotated. There is some flexibility in deciding what qualifies as a word: the minimum requirement is that two characters separated by a space are in different words, and that two alphabetic characters (`a-zA-Z`) separated only by alphabetic characters are in the same word.
- The desired direction of rotation should be inferred from the test cases below.

#### Test cases

Input: `I'm a badly written text. Some lunatic guy played with the order of vowels. Please fix me !`
Output: `I'm a bydla wrettin text. Semo lanituc gyu plyead with the erdor of vewols. Plaese fix me !`

Input: `AeiOuy`
Output: `EioUya`

Input: `Hyphenated-word`
Output: `Hephanetyd-word` or `Hephanetod-wyrd`

Comment: Define *vowel*.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Isn't that clear from the question ?

Comment: Damn, the Ruby answer was very good, apart the minor fact it did exactly the opposite. I hope to see it again.

Comment: I heva a neci 114-charectar sulotion in ceffeiscropt, but it braeks the charectar cesa. Deos that meka it anvilid?

Comment: Do I need to preserve the cesa?

Comment: @JanDvorak eys ouy need.

Comment: Then ouy won't see my sulituon and I'll heva to wreti a new eno.

Comment: I leki "preserve" in this centoxt.

Comment: Mya I ussema that aech word is iether lewarcose, Upparcese or SCRAIMANG-CESE?

Comment: What is the cerroct fix for "screaming-case"? "scraimang-cese", or "scraimeng-cesa"?

Comment: The question is deliberately opaque. Given that there are several possible definitions (among others, only the 10 code-points corresponding to `aeiouAEIOU` in ASCII / Basic Latin; those code-points plus any others in Basic Latin and Latin-1 Supplement which have those basic characters combined with a diacritic), the question should be explicit.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I assume ASCII

Comment: @JanDvorak For "screaming-case", both solutions would be accepted. Don't assume the case, just keep it based on char position.

Comment: The game should not be about guessing the problem. See the [FAQ](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic): "All **questions** on this site, whether a programming puzzle or a code golf, should have … A clear specification of what constitutes a correct submission."

Comment: I added a Ruby solution

Comment: Why are these answers treating `y` as a vowel?

Comment: @Gareth because the question did it too.

Comment: @dystroy But the question was asked in english so the reasonable assumption (given that vowel is not explicitly defined) is that you are talking about vowels in the english language: `[aeiou]`. Without an explicit definition (as requested by Peter Talyor in the first comment) it's impossible to judge whether the given answers are correct or not.

Comment: @Gareth There was a legitimate error in the question. I'm sorry for that. I think it's clear now ?

Comment: Wouldn't "Some" become "Semo"? (First test case)

Comment: If nobody is writing another answer or can point a problem in the GolfScript one, I'll accept it.

Comment: @dystroy, you can unaccept an answer or change the accepted answer, so if someone is currently working on an answer and it turns out to be shorter they'll post it anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### GolfScript, <strike>68</strike> <strike>67</strike> 57 characters

```
" "/{..+{95&"AEIOUY"?)}:C,1>\{.C!!{96&\(31&@|}*}%\;}%" "*
```

Input must be given on STDIN. Example ([online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJZb3UhISEgSSdtIGEgYmFkbHkgd3JpdHRlbiB0ZXh0LiBTb21lIGx1bmF0aWMgZ3V5IHBsYXllZCB3aXRoIHRoZSBvcmRlciBvZiB2b3dlbHMuIFBsZWFzZSBmaXggbWUgISIKCiIgIi97Li4rezk1JiJBRUlPVVkiPyl9OkMsMT5cey5DISF7OTYmXCgzMSZAfH0qfSVcO30lIiAiKgo%3D&run=true)):

```
> You!!! I'm a badly written text. Some lunatic guy played with the order of vowels. Please fix me !
Ouy!!! I'm a bydla wrettin text. Semo lanituc gyu plyead with the erdor of vewols. Plaese fix me !
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Ruby, <strike>91</strike> 90 characters

```
$><<gets.gsub(/\S+/){|x|x.gsub(r=/[aeiouy]/i){|y|z=$'[r]||x[r];y>?Z?z.downcase: z.upcase}}
```

#### Coffeescript, 148 charectars

```
alert prompt().replace /\S+/g,(x)->x.replace r=/[aeiouy](?=(.*))/gi,(y,z)->((t=z.match r)&&t[0]||x.match(r)[0])[['toLow','toUpp'][y>'Z']+'erCase']()
```

No ussimtoans, except that "holf-cerract" is a word, and not my sulitoon.

Test:

```
> To test this program, simply enter a long sentence that appears half-broken
  To test this pragrom, sympli enter a long sentence that eppaars holf-brekan

> No MaTtEr HoW mUcH cAsE yOu uSe, It WoRkS
  No MeTtAr HoW mUcH cEsA oUy eSu, It WoRkS
```

Comment: Regarding the Ruby code: 1) spare 2 characters by using `$&` instead of the second `gsub()` block's y parameter; 2) spare 1 character by using `?Z` instead of `'Z'`.

Comment: @manatwork `$&` cannot be used because it is changed before I use it. `z=$'[r]` changes it. Concerning `?Z` - thanks, I totally forgot about this syntax.

Comment: Oops. No idea how I tested it yesterday so appeared to work…

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 159 characters

Didn't end up quite as short as I'd hoped, but I decided to post it anyway:

```
import Data.Char
f s=let(v,t)=foldr g(v,[])s in t
g x(v,t)=last$(v,x:t):[(x,c v:t)|c<-[toUpper,toLower],x`elem`map c"AEIOUY"]
main=interact$unwords.map f.words
```

**Ungolfed version:**

```
import Data.Char

rotateVowels :: String -> String
rotateVowels word = result
  where (vowel, result) = foldr step (vowel, []) word
        step ch (vowel, rest)
          | ch `elem` "AEIOUY" = (ch, toUpper vowel : rest)
          | ch `elem` "aeiouy" = (ch, toLower vowel : rest)
          | otherwise          = (vowel, ch : rest)

main = interact $ unwords . map rotateVowels . words
```

This is a nice example of how lazy evaluation can let you do cool tricks. In `rotateVowels`, each time a new vowel is found, it is passed on to the left, while replacing it with the one coming from the right. This part of the output from the fold is fed back as the input so that the leftmost vowel becomes the replacement for the rightmost one.

```
(vowel, result) = foldr step (vowel, []) word
 ^^^^^                        ^^^^^
 this part of the output      is part of the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 172 bytes

```python
for w in input().split():p=[];q=list(w);z=filter(lambda c:c in'aeiouyAEIOUY',q);x=z[1:]+z[:1];print''.join(y in z and[str.upper,str.lower][y>'Z'](x.pop(0))or y for y in q),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY9BT8MwDIXv@xUml7QwKga3VkXaAYmdhoQ4QFWhrHFpUJZkqUub/vmSTrLsJ0uf37ML1FnzuDRWYskYW1rrYQRlYrmBkjTrnVZx5q6s6uJSatVTMqbFXLZKE/pEi/NJCmjyJiJcoLJD2L8cjh@ffHtJi6mcq11e381VvqsL55UhzrNfq0wSVpsZhJFVTz4bnEO/XZW2I/q6Cs/8i9fJlDnrkoc0jckCtNcewUu6XWLgzbr4Xq2B3z7lGwCcsIH1n6ivfgs78DMIOAmpA4xeEaEBwokyeLdnBD0YQaqBnyGA0yKghFFRB9QhWC/Rg23hL4bSfQZvGkWP0KoJInrDNmyP6jiEKF6D6zCeQnk/Ro79Aw)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen fixed it